# how to avoid duplicates of attributes in xml c#?

Tags: c#, xml

A part of my XML looks like this:

```
<IOConfig>
  <Packet Name="PacketOut" RemoteAddress="10.0.2.223" RemotePort="2020" NetworkInterface="ETH0">
    <Signal Type="float" Name="x_out" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoom" UnityName="Out" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="y_out" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoom" UnityName="Out" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="z_out" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoom" UnityName="Out" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="alpha_out" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoom" UnityName="Out" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="theta_out" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoom" UnityName="Out" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="phi_out" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoom" UnityName="Out" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="x_out1" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneSlewing" UnityName="Out1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="y_out1" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneSlewing" UnityName="Out1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="z_out1" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneSlewing" UnityName="Out1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="alpha_out1" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneSlewing" UnityName="Out1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="theta_out1" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneSlewing" UnityName="Out1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="phi_out1" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneSlewing" UnityName="Out1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
  </Packet>
  <Packet Name="PacketIn" LocalPort="2021" NetworkInterface="ETH0">
    <Signal Type="float" Name="x_in" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoomCrash" UnityName="collider1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="y_in" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoomCrash" UnityName="collider1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="z_in" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoomCrash" UnityName="collider1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="alpha_in" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoomCrash" UnityName="collider1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="theta_in" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoomCrash" UnityName="collider1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
    <Signal Type="float" Name="phi_in" Unit="m/s" Routing="" UnityObject="CraneBoomCrash" UnityName="collider1" NetworkConvert="1"></Signal>
  </Packet>
</IOConfig>
```

The desired output is: Out, Out1, collider1.

That is, duplicate values of UnityName should not be printed. Can this be done?

Code snipped that reading duplicate values of UnityName:

```
public class XMLStringReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string slectedItem;
    private bool editing = false;

    public string signalsa;
    public XmlReaderSettings settings;

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if ( GUILayout.Button(slectedItem))
        {
            editing = true;
        }

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;

        using ( XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("D://Docs/Unity3D/cdp/UDPApplication/Components/UDPIOServer.xml", settings) ) 
        {
            while ( reader.Read() ) 
            {
                if ( reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element ) 
                {
                    if ( reader.HasAttributes ) 
                    {
                        if ( reader.GetAttribute("UnityName") != null ) 
                        {
                            signalsa = reader.GetAttribute("UnityName");
                            string [] signalsCDP = {signalsa};

                            if (editing)
                            {
                                for(int i =0; i < signalsCDP.Length; i++) 
                                {
                                    if (GUILayout.Button(signalsCDP[i]))
                                    {
                                        slectedItem = signalsCDP[i];
                                        editing = false;
                                        print(signalsCDP[i].ToString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Xml is just storage... if you don't want duplicates, *don't add duplicates*! where is the data coming from?

Comment: Where is the XML and what is driving the output you are expecting, the relevant code please

Comment: I has been updated my answer with exact xml

Comment: Well how are they duplicates, each one had a different `Name` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta He wants the distinct `UnityName`, not the distinct `Name`.

Comment: @RB. What i meant was the `UnityName` has then nothing to do with `Signal` but something more specific to `Packet` and more relevant as an attribute there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a collection containing distinct values. Then check whether the next attribute value is already in that collection. If not, add it to the collection and do whatever you need.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("your path", settings)) 
{
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) 
        {
            if (reader.HasAttributes) 
            {
                if (reader.GetAttribute("UnityName") != null) 
                {
                    signalsa = reader.GetAttribute("UnityName");
                    if (!values.Contains(signalsa))
                    {
                        values.Add(signalsa);
                        //rest of your code goes here...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for your task:

```
XElement x = XElement.Load("File containing your xml");
var list = x.Descendants("Signal")
            .Where(d => d.HasAttributes && d.Attribute("UnityName") != null)
            .Select(d => d.Attribute("UnityName").Value)
            .Distinct();
foreach (string s in list)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: actually I can't use LINQ in Unity3D :(

Comment: @TimTaker than it's enough for you to use the approach described in Max Pressburger's answer, using the `XmlReader`. Just use a buffer collection to store only distinct `UnityName`s there.

Comment: @TimTaker, please see my another answer, clarifying this approach on your code

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all values and add them with a contains check to a List/Dictionary/Array/Whatever. After that print the collected values.

Here´s the solution:

```
    internal static void PrintAttributeValues(XDocument scr)
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (XElement elem in scr.Descendants("Signal"))
        {
            if (!values.Contains(elem.Attribute("UnityName").Value))
            {
                values.Add(elem.Attribute("UnityName").Value);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < values.Count; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(values[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added this code to mine and it doesn't work :( Could you please add this solution to my code please?

Comment: Just use Konstantin Vasilcov's snipped.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to define the *XML Schema* for whatever XML you need apart from *Programmatic approach*. *XML Schema* ensures the compliance of the XML.

> An XML Schema describes the structure of an XML document.

Have a look at the following references:

1. [XML Schema Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp)
2. [XSD Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp)